# How to convert a list with same type of field to a data.frame in R

Tags: r, json, dataframe

I have a `list` and the field inside each list element is of same name(only values are different) and I need to convert that into a `data.frame` with column name is same as that of field name. Following is my list,

[Data input (data input in json format.json)](http://jsoneditoronline.org/?id=6ac572e0c8944afe9496c578346889d5)

```
library(rjson)
data <- fromJSON(file = "data input in json format.json")
head(data,3)
[[1]]
[[1]]$floors
[1] 5

[[1]]$elevation
[1] 15

[[1]]$bmi
[1] 23.7483


[[2]]
[[2]]$floors
[1] 4

[[2]]$elevation
[1] 12

[[2]]$bmi
[1] 23.764


[[3]]
[[3]]$floors
[1] 3

[[3]]$elevation
[1] 9

[[3]]$bmi
[1] 23.7797
```

And my expected `data.frame` is,

```
floors elevation     bmi
     5        15 23.7483
     4        12 23.7640
     3         9 23.7797
```

Can you help me to figure out this ?. 
Thanks in adavance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `jsonlite`.

```
library(jsonlite)
```

Then use `fromJSON()` and specify the path to your file (or alternatively a URL or the raw text) in the argument `txt`:

```
fromJSON(txt = 'path/to/json/file.json')
```

The result is:

```
     floors elevation     bmi
1         5        15 23.7483
2         4        12 23.7640
3         3         9 23.7797
```

If you prefer rjson, you could first read it as previously:

```
data <- rjson::fromJSON(file = 'path/to/json/file.json')
```

Then use `do.call()` and `rbind.data.frame()` to convert the list to a dataframe:

```
do.call("rbind.data.frame", data)
```

Alternatively to `do.call()`: use `data.table`s `rbindlist()` which is faster:

```
data.table::rbindlist(data)
```